# Extract and modify substring from file path

Tags: python, regex

I have a file path saved as `filepath` in the form of `/home/user/filename`. Some examples of what the filename could be:

```
'1990MAlogfile'
'Tantrologfile'
'2003RF_2004logfile'
```

I need to write something that turns the `filepath` into just part of the filename (but I do not have just the filename saved as anything yet). For example:

`/home/user/1990MAlogfile` becomes `'1990 MA'`, `/home/user/Tantrologfile` becomes `'Tantro'`, or `/home/user/2003RF_2004logfile` becomes `'2003 RF'`.

So I need everything after the last forward slash and before an underscore if it's present (or before the 'logfile' if it's not), and then I need to insert a space between the last number and first letter if there are numbers present. Then I'd like to save the outcome as `objkey`. Any idea on how I could do this? I was thinking I could use regex, but don't know how I would handle inserting a space in those certain cases.

Comment: What have to tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

```
def get_filename(filepath):

    import re

    temp = os.path.basename(example)[:-7].split('_')[0]

    a = re.findall('^[0-9]*', temp)[0]

    b = temp[len(a):]

    return ' '.join([a, b])


example = '/home/user/2003RF_2004logfile'

objkey = get_filename(example)
```

## Explanation

import regular expression package

```
import re
```

example filepath

```
example = '/home/user/2003RF_2004logfile'

/home/user/2003RF_2004logfile
```

get the filename and remove everything after the _

```
temp = example.split('/')[-1].split('_')[0]

2003RF
```

get the beginning portion (splits if numbers at the beginning)

```
a = re.findall('^[0-9]*', temp)[0]

2003
```

get the end portion

```
b = temp[len(a):]

RF
```

combine the beginning and end portions

```
return ' '.join([a, b])

2003 RF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, re, string
mystr = 'home/user/2003RF_2004logfile'
def format_str(str):
     end = os.path.split(mystr)[-1]
     m1 = re.match('(.+)logfile', end)
     try:
         this = m1.group(1)
         this = this.split('_')[0]
     except AttributeError:
         return None
     m2 = re.match('(.+[0-9])(.+)', this)
     try:
         return " ".join([m2.group(1), m2.group(2)])
     except AttributeError:
         return this
```